# Как сначала скоплировать данные из 2-x json файлов по ключу, а потом обьединить их в один файл, подставив в нужное место на Python

Tags: python, json

Нужно сначала обьединить 2 файла в новом файле формата json (в части values для всех value выбрать правильно по ключу, и в части value для основных id), которые имеют вид(значний болше, просто тут для примера):
Data 1:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "name1", "value": "", 
"values":
[{"id": 11, "name": "name2", "value": 
""},
{"id": 12, "name": "name3", "value": 
""}]}
```

и Data 2

```
{
"values": [{
  "id": 1,
  "value": "True"
}, {
  "id": 12,
  "value": "False"
}, {
  "id": 11,
  "value": "True"
}, ]
}
```

Так, чтобы в новом файле было так:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "name1", "value": "True", "values":
[{"id": 11, "name": "name2", "value": "True"},
{"id": 12, "name": "name3", "value": "False"}]}
```

Решаю с помощью pandas(Join) и json, но не понимаю как разделить разные "уровни" value и values, чтобы он искал правильные id и как подставить в эти values значния. Делаю вот так, но результат выходит неправилным

```
import json
import pandas as pd

file_path_1 = 'task3/tests.json'

with open(file_path_1, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file_1:
    data_1 = json.load(file_1)

file_path_2 = 'task3/values.json'

with open(file_path_2, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file_2:
    data_2 = json.load(file_2)

df1 = pd.DataFrame([data_1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([data_2])

  
df_join= df1.join(df2)
print (df_join)
```